# 502 bad gateway running homestead laravel website

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, homestead

Whenever I try loading a project I get a 502 bad gateway error. I have tried refreshing the page I still get 502 error. what could be the issue?

This is a brand new fresh install of homestead with virtual box version 12.2.0

```
---
ip: "192.168.56.56"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
  - map: D:/git_projects/laravel/jonneyje
    to: /home/vagrant/jonneyje
  - map: D:/git_projects/laravel/brockphotography
    to: /home/vagrant/brockphotography
  - map: D:/git_projects/laravel/capstone
    to: /home/vagrant/capstone
  - map: D:/git_projects/laravel/abcbooks
    to: /home/vagrant/abcbooks
  - map: D:/git_projects/laravel/phpmyadmin
    to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

sites:
  - map: jonneyje.test
    to: /home/vagrant/jonneyje/public
    php: "7.2"
  - map: brockphotography.test
    to: /home/vagrant/brockphotography/public
    php: "8.3.0"
  - map: capstone.test
    to: /home/vagrant/capstone/public
    php: "7.2"
  - map: abcbooks.test
    to: /home/vagrant/abcbooks/public
    php: "7.2"
  - map: phpmyadmin.test
    to: /home/vagrant/phpmyadmin

databases:
    - homestead
```

I have commented out the first top section of xdebug.ini `zend_extension=xdebug.so` and did absolutely nothing.
I also tried changing the php project version to 7.2 and I get a compatability error when accessing my project.

Comment: Check the nginx and php-fpm error.

Comment: I checked them both and they are still active and running without any errors

Comment: If you use proxy, check the proxy log. Include the forward proxy and the reverse proxy.

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to get back to you I did check all of the logs and I am getting no errors

Answer (score 1):

The temporary solution is to update your Homebrew PHP configuration.

Find the config file (it'll be named `homebrew.mxcl.php.plist` and it'll be in your Homebrew location, `/usr/local/` or `/etc/homebrew`, under the folder `Cellar/php/8.3.0`, assuming you're on PHP 8.3.0).

Edit that file and add the following:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY</key>
    <string>YES</string>
</dict>
```

You'll add this directly under this line:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

Now run `valet restart` and try again.

If that doesn't fix it, let's do a little more cleanup.

- Run `brew services stop php` to make sure you're not running PHP as your individual user (it should run as root)
- Delete any `homebrew.mxcl.php.plist` files that are in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (this is the list of launch agents for your individual user)
- Delete the `php83` sock file (`~/.config/valet/valet83.sock`) and then `valet install` again

This answer was copied [from here](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/1433#issuecomment-1655883465). I hope that will be useful. It solves similar questions for this problem in this platform. However, there was no answer to this. That's why I wanted to copy it here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the looks of it my install doesn't even have homebrew PHP  this is the install that I am using https://github.com/laravel/homestead